# Adding event listener to Stripe JS button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

```
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_dNbyQ3qsyTe8IAikxSfnLhBl"
data-amount= <%= number_to_currency(@shopping_cart.total) * 100 %>
data-name="Abound"
data-description="Checkout"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-locale="auto">
document.querySelectorAll('.stripe-button').addEventListener('click',function(){
  <%= @shopping_cart.clear %>
}
```

This is a stripe button that processes payments. The problem is the Eventlistener.  Every time I refresh the page or go to a different page the ruby code gets executed and my cart is cleared. Anyone have any ideas? 
Even if I change the js to make it invalid the ruby gets executed can you also explain this as well?

Full page being loaded:

```
    <h1>Shopping Cart Contents</h1>
    <div style="font-size: 14px; "> <%= render :partial => 'shopping_cart_item', :collection => @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_it  ems %> </div>
    <div style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Total:</strong><%= number_to_currency (@shopping_cart.total) %></div>
  <form>
    <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_dNbyQ3qsyTe8IAikxSfnLhBl"
    data-amount= <%= number_to_currency(@shopping_cart.total) * 100 %>
>>  data-name="Abound"
    data-description="Checkout"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
    document.querySelectorAll('.stripe-button').addEventListener('click',function(){
      <%= @shopping_cart.clear %>
    }
    </script>
  </form>

  </div>
```

Edit:
What I ended up doing is just creating a new view page for the cart since Ruby is loaded server side and thus does not play well embedded in js.

Comment: How is that interpolation evaluated? What's in the actual HTML when you load the page?

Comment: How can adding an event listener to button have anything to do with cart getting cleared on server when page refreshes? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @aluan I added the full file

Comment: @charlietfl I have ruby code in the event listener that clears the cart. This code is being executed regardless is the JS conditions are met.

Comment: ruby runs on server .... not in browser. That I think is your whole problem `<%= @shopping_cart.clear %>` will execute on server every time...not when event fires in browser

Comment: So i would need to do this all in ruby? <% if button clicked % >  clear    ?

Comment: Or just redirect to a new URL and put the code there might be a better solution?

Comment: @charlietfl could you copy and paste your comment as an answer, this helped me a lot, and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ruby runs on server .... not in browser...... javascript is the opposite

Your issue is that  `<%= @shopping_cart.clear %>` will execute on server every time...not when event fires in browser.

i would suggest you use ajax to send  something to server and then clear cart in that request as appropriate